# Use InputStream multiple times

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I have a view, from which the user can first generate a PDF depending on some parameters, and then download and/or send it via mail.

Now, the method for generating the PDF file  returns an `InputStream`, which I then store as field of the class, like this:

```
public class PDFWindow extends VerticalLayout {
    ...
    private InputStream pdfInputStream;
    ...

    private void createPDF() {
        this.pdfInputStream = pdfCreator.createPDF();  
}
```

My problem is, that the `pdfInputStream` is closed after it is consumed by the `FileDownloader`:

```
Button download = new Button("Download");
final FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(
            new StreamResource(() -> this.pdfInputStream, this.pdfFileName));
fileDownloader.extend(download);
```

or the `SpringEmailService` I wrote:

```
SpringEmailService.send(
     "test@mail.com", recipients, this.subject.getValue(),
     this.message.getValue(),this.pdfInputStream,"test.pdf", "application/pdf");
```

Is there any way, to stop the `InputStream` from being closed and then closing it manual, or should I look for a completely different way?

Comment: Just don't store an InputStream as a field. Ask the creator to create the stream every time you need one. If it's too expensive, then store the generated bytes in memory, or in a file, or in your database, or wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I changed it so, that I store the byte Array as a field instead, and it works perfectly. Could you post an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't store an InputStream as a field.

Ask the creator to create the stream every time you need one.

If it's too expensive, then store the generated bytes in memory, or in a file, or in your database, or wherever you want, and create a stream over these bytes/file whenever you need one.